# Function at a theme for wordpress, Helping to edit something

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been installing a Wordpress Theme, the theme has a custom navigation function.
It shows a page navigation at archive, categories but doesn't show at tag.

This is the function from functions.php

```
<?php  function wp_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '', $prelabel = '', $nxtlabel = '', $pages_to_show = 5, $always_show = false) {
 global $request, $posts_per_page, $wpdb, $paged;
 if(empty($prelabel)) {   $prelabel = '<strong>&laquo;</strong>';
 } if(empty($nxtlabel)) {
 $nxtlabel = '<strong>&raquo;</strong>';
 } $half_pages_to_show = round($pages_to_show/2);
 if (!is_single()) {
 if(!is_category()) {
 preg_match('#FROM\s(.*)\sORDER BY#siU', $request, $matches);  } else {
 preg_match('#FROM\s(.*)\sGROUP BY#siU', $request, $matches);  }
 $fromwhere = $matches[1];
 $numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM $fromwhere");
 $max_page = ceil($numposts /$posts_per_page);
 if(empty($paged)) {
 $paged = 1;
 }
 if($max_page > 1 || $always_show) {
 echo "$before <div class='Nav'><span>Pages ($max_page): </span>";   if ($paged >= ($pages_to_show-1)) {
 echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link().'">&laquo; First</a> ... ';  }
 previous_posts_link($prelabel);
 for($i = $paged - $half_pages_to_show; $i <= $paged + $half_pages_to_show; $i++) {   if ($i >= 1 && $i <= $max_page) {   if($i == $paged) {
 echo "<strong class='on'>$i</strong>";
 } else {
 echo ' <a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a> ';   }
 }
 }
 next_posts_link($nxtlabel, $max_page);
 if (($paged+$half_pages_to_show) < ($max_page)) {
 echo ' ... <a href="'.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'">Last &raquo;</a>';   }
 echo "</div> $after";
 }
 }
}
?>
```

I hope anyone helping with that function to show page navigation at tag, thanks.

Comment: This a link for archive
http://www.uimgs.com/blog/2010/09/ 
& this for a category
http://www.uimgs.com/blog/category/very_funny/
and this for a tag
http://www.uimgs.com/blog/tag/funny/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing the wrong match. Change `if(!is_category())` into `if(!is_category()&&!is_tag())`